# Get rows by column in Laravel Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Laravel Many to Many relation**

Hi, I am stuck trying to get the data from database by weeks.

I have the next table (Many to Many relation)

1. routine: id, plan_id, user_id.
2. exercise: id, name, description, image.
3. exercise_routine: id, routine_id, exercise_id, week, day.

**Relations**

Routine

```
public function exercises() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Exercise::class)->withPivot('week', 'day', 'completed')->orderBy('week','asc');;
}
```

Exercise

```
public function routines() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Routine::class)->withPivot('week', 'day', 'completed');
}
```

I would like to get all the rows by week like this.

```
    Json example:
    {
      "week": [
        1: {
         "exercises": [
           {
             "name": "Abs"
           }
         ]
        },
        2: {
         ...
        }
      ]

    }
```

I already tried this

```
 if(!empty($routine)) {

            foreach ($routine->exercises as $exercise) {
                $week = $exercise->pivot->week;

                if($week == $previous_week) {
                    array_push($this->weeks, $exercise->pivot->week);
                } else {
                    array_push($this->weeks, [
                        $exercise->pivot->week => $exercise->pivot->week
                    ]);
                }

                $previous_week = $exercise->pivot->week;

            }

//            dd($this->weeks);

//            return DB::table('exercise_routine')->where('routine_id',$routine->id)->max('week');
        }
```

**The explanation**

exercise_routine table has a week number to separate exercises by week.
I need to create an array and if the week is 1, then push in the array 1, if the next is 1, push in the same array. If the next is 2 or different just push but in the number 2.

I am not sure if you can understand what I mean, it is just trying to get the way to do it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make models and define relationships. With this way you will be able to get the data in your desired format. Means it will automatically define levels for you.

Comment: You mean, I define a model in the many to many relation? exercise_routine?

Comment: Yes, If you define a relationship in exerice_routine model which belongs to routines and also exercise models. So you will query first model which exercise_routine and you will eager load other two relations with it. So it will give you a level structure.

Comment: Yeah but that not resolve my question, it is about to get the data and push arrays, so it is not about relation.

Comment: Well I have done something this in a project but with query builder joining in laravel. My case was something like this, I had products, purchases, return_products, return_purchases and all these have to be in a created_at date order, there were 10 or 12 tables joining I think. If this is what suits you then let me know.

Comment: Yes maybe it can help me! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the collection method [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-maptogroups) can help you simplify grouping up the `exercises`.

Here's an example on how I would use it for your case:

```
if(!empty($routine)){
  // creating groups of exercise by week [1 => ['abs'], 2 => []]
  $exerciseWeeks = $routine->exercises->mapToGroups(function($exercise, $k){
      return [$exercise->pivot->weeks => $exercise->name];
    })
    ->map(function($exerciseInWeek, $k){ // creating your json format from here point on
      $weekObj = new \stdClass;
      $weekObj->exercises = [];
      foreach($exerciseInWeek as $exerciseName){
        $exerciseObj = new \stdClass;
        $exerciseObj->name = $exerciseName;
        $weekObj->exercises[] = $exerciseObj;
      }
      return $weekObj;
    });

  // creates the final json object
  $routineObj = new \stdClass;
  $routineObj->week = $exerciseWeeks->all();

  $finalRoutineJSON = json_encode($routineObj);
}
```